# Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
class SecondViewController:UIViewController {
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //Custom logic here
  }
}
```

Quite a newbie question:

a view controller(SecondViewController), inherent from UIViewController needs a designated init function like above.

In this case, how should I call it, given I am not sure what the value for "coder" should be? I used to call the controller as: SecondViewController(), but it gives:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call
```

I understand coder parameter has to be provided, but want to ask what its value comes from.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the answers from @Chackle. Finally the solution I figured out is below.

What I want:

- Inherit my `SecondViewController` from `UIViewController`
- Simply to initialize any new `SecondViewController` as `SecondViewController()`

Solution:

```
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        //Do whatever you want here
    }
```

`"required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)"` is a must if you create a subclass of `UIViewController`. And so is `"super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)"`, because it is the way how `UIViewController` does initialization.