# Calling subclass function from different class

Tags: swift, oop

I'm new to swift. How can I call func print on my CallerViewController class

```
   class CallerViewController: UIViewController {

       var subViewController: SubViewController!
       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
             subViewController = SubViewController() // this is throwing Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call
             subViewController.printHello()
       }
   }
```

Subclass

```
   class SubViewController: SuperViewController {
       func printHello(){
          print("Hello World")
       }
   }
```

Super class

```
   class SuperViewController: UIViewController {
   }
```

Comment: Related ?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30339712/6576315

Comment: If you need to access that function from different view controllers then maybe it’s better to place it in a separate, non view controller, class or struct. What is the real world use case for that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit the SubViewController in CallerViewController

```
 class CallerViewController: SubViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        printHello()
    }
}

class SubViewController: SuperViewController {
    func printHello() {
        print("Hello World")
    }
}

class SuperViewController: UIViewController {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are not creating your `UIViewController` instance called `SubViewController` the correct way. Here is some guideline how to create `UIViewController` . For the sake of this guideline I call it `TestViewController`. Just to mention the guideline is using Storyboard based layout (as you do)

1. create new swift file and create `TestViewController` with this code:

   ```
    class TestViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      }

      func printHello(){
        print("Hello World")
      }
    }
   ```
2. Create new `UIViewController` in `main.storyboard` file by clicking "+" button in right top corner and typing "UIViewController"
3. Assign `TestViewController` as a class to your storyboard `UIViewController`
4. Assign some identifier (TestIdentifier) to your storyboard `UIViewController` [image: picture]
5. you can finally create `TestViewController` instance from storyboard by calling this function:

   ```
    func createUIViewControllerAndCallPrintHello() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let testViewController =   storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestIdentifier") as! TestViewController
    testViewController.printHello()
    }
   ```